# Can I make a batch file unable to close itself until a timer runs out?

Tags: file, batch-file

It's okay if you didn't understand the title. I'll explain here:

I have a timer in a batch file. Is there any BASIC command that I can use so that the batch file cannot be closed (even by clicking the "X" in the corner) until the timer runs out?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you speaking about windows `cmd` batch files? `*.bat|*.cmd`?

Comment: That's the extension for a batch file, yes.

Comment: There is ways to hide it so it is not so easy to close but about ignoring normal close (_was that wm_close|wm_quit..?_) I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific command or any simple way to do this. You can start the file hidden (not on the "hotbar" down the bottom or on the screen), but it will still show up on task manager. If you want it to do things that don't involve user input, that's the way to go.